# How to mix and match different items to form different combination in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, match

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to mix the food and drink together to form different combination. Since there are 4 type of food and 4 type of drink, which means there will be 16 types of different combination. I managed to automate the food in column F by repeating 4 times (since there are 4 type of drink) for each type of food, however, I have no idea how to automate the drink in column G to complete the 16 different combination.

When I added in new food and drink in Column B & C, ideally the new possible combination will appear in Column F & G as well.

Column I & J are the expected output that I desired. Hope to get some advice from expert. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YW5_dfCSQ4BTnA09iss3wa9dWHGDlGjqoDRJ9buMDO0/edit#gid=792268474

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in D1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Food","Drink"; SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&"|"&TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>""))),"|")})`

This one formula creates the headers and all results in Columns D and E.

The header text can be changed within the formula as you like.

The rest just concatenates every non-null food value with a pipe symbol ("|") and a `TRANSPOSE`d list of every non-null drink value, forming a virtual 2D grid. That is `FLATTEN`ed into one column and then `SPLIT` at the pipe symbol back into two columns.

The formula will "keep up with" new food and/or drink items added (or any removed from either list). The lists need not have the same number of items either.

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
=INDEX({FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(B6:B&"♦"), COUNTA(C6:C)),  "♦")),       
        FLATTEN(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(C6:C&"♦",  COUNTA(B6:B))), "♦"))})
```